# jQuery Validator validate only first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

Hi guys Im using Jquery validator in my react project but I'm not sure where should I implement validator settings , now they are in `componentDidMount` in my component which is opening modal for adding elements and I dont thinks that it is right to define them every time I open modal dialog but I dont know where else I can put them also the validation for start date <= end date is running only the first time ... Can someone help ?

my react component:

```
var ModalAddElement = React.createClass({displayName: "ModalAddElement",
    getInitialState() {
        return {
            show: false,
            items:this.props.items,
            shouldValidate:false
        };
    },
    componentDidMount() {
        jQuery(document.body.children[0].children[0]).bind('mousewheel', function (e) {
            var evt = window.event || e
            evt = evt.originalEvent ? evt.originalEvent : evt;
            var delta = evt.detail ? evt.detail * (-40) : evt.wheelDelta
            if (delta > 0) {
                this.value = parseInt(this.value) + 1;
            }
            else {
                this.value = parseInt(this.value) - 1;
            }
        });
        jQuery.validator.addMethod("validStartDate", function(value,element) {
            if (moment(value, "MM/DD/YYYY", true).isValid()) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        },'&nbsp; Enter valid date in format "mm/dd/yyyy" !');
        jQuery.validator.addMethod("validEndDate", function(value,element) {
            if (moment(value, "MM/DD/YYYY", true).isValid()) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        },'&nbsp; Enter valid date in format "mm/dd/yyyy" !');
        jQuery.validator.addMethod("checkEndDate",
            function(value, element, params) {
                var startDate = new Date($('#addStartDatePicker').val());
                var endDate = new Date($('#addEndDatePicker').val());
                if (startDate <= endDate || isNaN(startDate.getTime()) || isNaN(endDate.getTime())){
                    return true;
                }
                else{
                    return false;
                }
            },'&nbsp; End date should be equal or greater than start date !');
        jQuery.validator.addMethod("checkStartDate",
            function(value, element, params) {
                var startDate = new Date($('#addStartDatePicker').val());
                var endDate = new Date($('#addEndDatePicker').val());

                if (startDate <= endDate || isNaN(startDate.getTime()) || isNaN(endDate.getTime())){
                    return true;
                }
                else{
                    return false;
                }
            },'&nbsp; Start date should be earlier or equal to end date !');
    },
    showModal() {
        this.setState({show: true});
    },
    hideModal() {
        this.setState({show: false});
    },
    handleStartDateValidation:function(){
        if(this.state.shouldValidate) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('#addStartDatePicker').valid({
                    errorClass: 'error'
                });
            }.bind(this), 100);
        }
    },
    handleEndDateValidation:function(){
        if(this.state.shouldValidate) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('#addEndDatePicker').valid({
                    errorClass: 'error'
                });
            }.bind(this), 100);
        }
    },
    handleWorkHoursValidation:function(){
        if(this.state.shouldValidate) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('#addWorkHours').valid({
                    errorClass: 'error'
                });
            }.bind(this), 100);
        }
    },
    fireStartDateDatepicker:function(){
        $('#addStartDatePicker').datepick({
            showAnim:''
        })
    },
    fireEndDateDatepicker:function() {
        $('#addEndDatePicker').datepick({
            showAnim:''
        });
    },
    addElement:function () {
        var workHours = this.workHours.value;
        var startDate = this.startDate.value;
        var endDate = this.endDate.value;
        var objectToAdd = {start:startDate,end:endDate,hours:workHours,selected:false};
        var validOverlappingCheck = true;
        this.setState({shouldValidate:true});
        $('#addStartDatePicker').valid();
        $('#addEndDatePicker').valid();
        $('#addWorkHours').valid();
        for(var i = 0;i<this.state.items.length;i++)
        {
            if (!(this.state.items[i].end < objectToAdd.start || objectToAdd.end < this.state.items[i].start)) {
                validOverlappingCheck = false;
            }
        }
        if(  $('#addStartDatePicker').valid() && $('#addEndDatePicker').valid() && $('#addWorkHours').valid()) {
            if (validOverlappingCheck) {
                this.props.onAddElement(objectToAdd);
                this.setState({shouldValidate: false});
                this.setState({show: false});
            }
            else {
                sweetAlert({
                    title: "",
                    text: "In order to merge your diaries after, they should not contain overlapping periods.Please enter different period.",
                    type: "warning"
                });
                return;
            }
        }
        else {
            return;
        }
    },
    render : function(){
        var close = () => this.setState({ show: false});
        return (
            <ReactBootstrap.ButtonToolbar>
                <button className="myButton" onClick={() => this.setState({ show: true})}>Add period</button>
                <ReactBootstrap.Modal show={this.state.show} onHide={this.hideModal} dialogClassName="custom-modal">
                    <form className="myForme" noValidate>
                    <ReactBootstrap.Modal.Header closeButton>
                        <ReactBootstrap.Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-lg">Add period to diary</ReactBootstrap.Modal.Title>
                        <p>Date period should be valid e.g (start date should be less or equal to end date)</p>
                    </ReactBootstrap.Modal.Header>
                    <ReactBootstrap.Modal.Body>
                            <div>
                                <span>Enter Start Date: <span className="red">*</span> </span>
                                <input type="text" className="myDatepicker" id="addStartDatePicker"  name="start" data-rule-checkStartDate="true" data-rule-validStartDate="true"  onFocus={this.fireStartDateDatepicker} placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" onBlur={this.handleStartDateValidation}  ref={(ref) => this.startDate = ref}  required></input>
                            </div>

                            <div>
                                <span>Enter End Date: <span className="red">*</span> </span>
                                <input type="text" className="myDatepicker2" id="addEndDatePicker" name="end" data-rule-validDate="true" data-rule-checkEndDate="true" data-rule-validEndDate="true"  onFocus={this.fireEndDateDatepicker} placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" onBlur={this.handleEndDateValidation}  ref={(ref) => this.endDate = ref}  required></input>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <span>Enter Work Hours: <span className="red">*</span> </span>
                                <input className="hoursInput"  name="hours" id="addWorkHours" onInput={this.handleWorkHoursValidation} placeholder="0-60" onBlur={this.handleWorkHoursValidation} type="number" min="0"  max="60" ref={(ref) => this.workHours = ref} required/>
                            </div>
                    </ReactBootstrap.Modal.Body>
                    <ReactBootstrap.Modal.Footer>
                        <span className="asteriskAlign"><span className="red">*</span> - required</span>
                            <ReactBootstrap.Button bsStyle="primary"  onClick={this.addElement}>Add</ReactBootstrap.Button>
                            <ReactBootstrap.Button bsStyle="primary" onClick={this.hideModal}>Close</ReactBootstrap.Button>
                    </ReactBootstrap.Modal.Footer>
                        </form>
                </ReactBootstrap.Modal>
            </ReactBootstrap.ButtonToolbar>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: You'll have to reset the date function after it's checked the first time

Comment: For the other components of the question, it would help if you could create a jsfiddle or codepen

Comment: how can I reset it ?